# Making a php script that supports modules

Tags: php

Ok, this is kind of non-descriptive, but I wish to make a site in which I am able to add and remove "functions" via adding and removing php modules.
Basically, is it possible to make a site like a framework where you can insert and remove various php modules, similar to how you can enable and disable modules in any other program
Does this make any sense? :)

Comment: Of course it can be done.  This sounds like pretty much any/every current PHP framework.

Comment: Any ideas on how I would do that though? Dynamically loading and executing pieces of php?

Comment: There are limitless ways you could do it. The question is how do you want to do it/what are you trying to achieve?  Do you just want to load and execute every PHP file in a particular directory, or do you want a rhyme and reason as to what is loaded and when?  Find an existing framework (I like CodeIgniter) and look at how controllers, models, libraries, etc. are loaded.  You just might decide to not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is design the Interface of your core application to the various plugins (or modules...) .

For example, you can decide that all plugins must have a certain directory structure.
This enables, for example your core libary to know where to find view files, new classes etc.

You might want to decide that All plugins have a the same name init file, where you write all the plugin initialization codes, same with other events (init, end etc).

All plugins that are to integrate into a specific menu in your core app should have a menue.php or some other, strictly named and structured  configuration file that will tell your core library which menu to integrate it and what will be the texts etc etc.

**CORE APPLICATION**
The core application should have hookups in various important places, hookups that plugins can use/overidde to change behavior of the core application.

I would also suggest adding events, which is similar to behaviors, just that this time the core app triggers it and calls all functions who where registered to the event.

**SUGGESTION**
While I personally do not like Elgg too much, the way they designed it will let you understand pretty well how to design a FW which is easily expendable with plug-ins (try tha same with Joomla, wordpress).

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. I just wasn't sure if something like this would be a little out of the league of php

Comment: @BraunShedd, no no, not out of the league of php, people have been doing this for years now with PHP.

Comment: @BraunShedd Facebook runs on PHP. It can handle a modular structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both procedural and objected-oriented ways.

Write bunch of functions or classes and then include or require that file

when you using them.

[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

[include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

[require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

[require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

can be used to use those functions and classes

Comment: There's a lot more to a good modular system than a few includes.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have explained a general way to do it. Instead of using frameworks.I don't think I deserve down vote on this.